# C - After getting the number by scanf, but there wrong result caluclated

Tags: c

I have a question.

I coded one simple calculator for wage.

but when I print out the result, there are wrong number printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

int main() {

```
int info[14][5];
int id=0, wage=0, hour=0;   //사원번호, 시급, 시간  
int total_hour=0, total_basic_wage=0, total_overtime_wage =0, total_result=0; //맨 마지막 합계 값들을 저장할 것들 

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {

    scanf("%d",&id);

    if(id == 0) {
        break;
    } else {


    scanf("%d %d",&wage,&hour);
        info[i][0] = id; 
        info[i][1] = wage;
        info[i][2] = hour; 
        total_hour += hour;

        if(hour<40){ //

        info[i][3] = hour * wage;
        total_basic_wage += info[i][3];

        info[i][4] = 0;
        total_overtime_wage += info[i][4];
        } else{

        info[i][3] = 40 * wage;
        total_basic_wage += info[i][3];
        info[i][4] = (hour-40) * wage * 1.5;
        total_overtime_wage += info[i][4]; 
        }

        info[i][5] = info[i][3] + info[i][4];
        total_result += info[i][5]; 

    }   

}

printf("This is results\n");
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {

printf("%d\t",info[i][0]); 
printf("%d\t",info[i][1]);
printf("%d\t",info[i][2]);
printf("%d\t",info[i][3]);
printf("%d\t",info[i][4]);
printf("%d\t",info[i][5]);
printf("\n");
}
```

}

When I put, 1,10,10,2,10,45
the Result should be 
This is results

1   10  10  100 0   100

2   10  45  400 75  475

3   10  40  400 0   400

However the result shows like this
This is results

1   10  10  100 0   2
2   10  45  400 75  3
3   10  40  400 0   400

Is because I used the scanf? 
thank you for ur help in advanced :)

Comment: [Both GCC and Clang warn for this with warnings enabled](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Sef3dW)

Comment: Please be aware this code is C, not C++.

Comment: Your code is C,  not C++. So read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Read [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of *every function* that you use, in particular [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) which *can fail*

Comment: Please notice that *StackOverflow* is *not* a *do-my-homework* website.